# Magento 2: Install Extension over Web Setup Wizard error

Tags: magento2, installation, web-setup-wizard

Install Extension over Web Setup Wizard gives an error that you see below.

- I checked my cron and its working
- I set the files permission to 777 for testing and it's still not working.

Could you please advise me what could be the problem and what are the possible causes for this?

[image]

Comment: To solve the "check con script" issue you need to run this command `php bin/magento cron:run` with 777 permission of var folder

Comment: I did. The message is: Ran jobs by schedule.

Comment: Now refresh the page and check the rediness check issues

Comment: I sadly get the same erros as listed above.